# Lighthouse graphql subscriptions

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Can anyone tell me how to use lighthouse graphql subscriptions, i did all the steps as explained here https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html but when mobile team (android and ios ) trying to use it, it asking them to enter websocket endpoint so how can i make this websocket with graphql lighthouse subscription, i know about laravel websocket in general but how to connect this websockets with graphql lighthouse subscription?

Answer (score 5):

The Lighthouse subscriptions are sent through the [Pusher](http://pusher.com)-service by default. When you run following query, Lighthouse will then register the subscription server-side.

```
subscription PostUpdated {
    postUpdated(id: 123) {
        title
    }
}
```

The query will return a Pusher-channel (see example below). Any events in the subscription you just created, will be sent to this channel. Your client-side implementation has to be able to subscribe to Pusher-messages. If you are using Apollo or Relay modern, you can take a look at the snippets in the Lighthouse-docs.

```
{
  "data": {
    "postUpdated": null
  },
  "extensions": {
    "lighthouse_subscriptions": {
      "version": 1,
      "channels": {
        "PostUpdated": "private-lighthouse-wlAyAuW8aBlthctY2rkRGRlaaGq30Iqr-1564126310"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Every time there are changes to the post with ID 123, you should receive a message through Pusher, with the queried data. Please note that you have to either use the `@broadcast` directive or manually trigger the subscription, see [trigger subscriptions](https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html#trigger-subscriptions) for more information.

Comment: Are there any way to change the channel private-lighthouse-... to something else?

Answer (score 0):

you need use 4.18 version, the rest is the same as the documentation